# gitlab push via ssh require password

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I have successfully installed `gitlab` on our company's server. And I have tested the ssh way to pull/push the modified files. It works well in my macbook.
However, My workmates use windows 7 for development.

So when I helped them to config the ssh key for the `gitlab` according the (gitlab's document)[ http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html ],it doesn't work.

Every time when they push the modified files to the `gitlab`, it require's them to type password.
I don't know why is this happening, so please help me out.

Comment: From the project root, open .git/config file and change the url from `http` to `ssh` one, in the `[remote "origin"]` section

Comment: In xor's answer, "change the url from http to ssh" means to copy the ssh version of the url from your repository's 'clone' dropdown on the GitLab site and use that, not simply edit the .git/config and replace 'https' or 'http' with 'ssh'.  You'll have a 'git@' instead of the http:// and probably be replacing a / with a : between the domain and your groupname within the url.

Answer (score 2):

It asks for password if you have not added the ssh-key to your gitlab account. I use windows 7 and this is what I did.
open git bash
type ssh-keygen and accept defaults 
clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
go to gitlab account -> add ssh-key and paste there.
I can now clone fine from there to my local windows 7 machine and work and push to remote fine.